# Monitor going black for no reason

Tags: hardware, monitor

Ok so, my monitor is going black on random occasions. Mostly it is when i watch a video. It doesn't matter if it is on youtube, facebook, udemy or whatever other site.
I checked my cables they are all good. I also turned off the screen saver.
Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there could be many reasons for this - bad drivers, bad cables, bad screen, GPU overheating and melting solder connections (I've experienced this).

the easiest thing to check is to see if the issue is in the computer itself. to do that, connect to a different monitor (using a different cable).

to check if it's a software issue, you could try running a LiveCD of a different OS on your computer (for example, Fedora or Ubuntu).

if the issue still happens even with a different OS, then it's likely a GPU problem - you'll need to either get that replaced, replace the mainboard (if GPU is integrated), or replace the computer...